# How to create a matrix of pointers using smart pointers for a class?

Tags: c++, class, smart-pointers

Let's say we have the following code in c-style

```
class Dog {
public:
    void woof() {};
};

int main() {
    Dog* mat[5][5];

    mat[0][0] = new Dog();
    
    mat[0][0]->woof();
}
```

How would you write it in cpp style using smart pointers? is the following is fine?

```
class Dog {
public:
    void woof() {};
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Dog> mat[5][5];

    mat[0][0] = std::make_unique<Dog>();
    
    mat[0][0]->woof();

}
```

or maybe even something such as:

```
class Dog {
public:
    void woof() {};
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<Dog>[]>[]> mat = std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<Dog>[]>[]>(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        mat[i] = std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<Dog>[]>(5);

    mat[0][0] = std::make_unique<Dog>();
    
    mat[0][0]->woof();

}
```

how can I do it in the most elegant and memory-efficient way?

Comment: This is ```c++```, not ```c```.

Comment: In C++ you should do std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Dog>>>

Comment: > `how can I do it in the most elegant and memory-efficient way?`
It might be different for your actual use case, but from what you've shown us, what you have is fine. As in "will work". "Elegant" is fairly subjective, however, you might prefer `std::array` over a c-style array if you know the bounds ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

If the dimensions are fixed, which I think they are, then you can use `std::array`. Then loop through and fill the elements with `std::generate`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

class Dog {
public:
    void woof() { std::cout << "woof" << std::endl; };
};


int main() {
    std::array<std::array<std::unique_ptr<Dog>, 5>, 5> matrix;

    for (int x=0; x < 5; ++x)
    {
        std::generate(std::begin(matrix[x]), std::end(matrix[x]), 
            []{ return std::make_unique<Dog>(); } );
    }

    matrix[0][0]->woof();
    matrix[4][4]->woof();
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YW8r7c)